# How can i get avg,sum of sub attribute?

Tags: rethinkdb

I have problem with writing average query!

In my Rethink db, i have some documents in one table like this:

document1:

```
{
    a:{
        last:3
    },
    b:{
        last:4
    },
    c:{
        last:6
    },
}
```

document2:

```
{
    a:{
        last:7
    },
    b:{
        last:9
    },
    c:{
        last:2
    },
}
```

document3:

```
{
    a:{
        last:5
    },
    b:{
        last:8
    },
    c:{
        last:4
    },
}
```

I want to get average of last attribute in every object like this:

```
{
    sum_a_last:15,
    sum_b_last:21,
    sum_c_last:12,
    avg_a_last:5,
    avg_b_last:7,
    avg_c_last:4
}
```

What is the query to return this result?

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you're looking for is

```
r.db('dbName').table('tableName').avg((doc) => doc('a')('last'));
```

If you're trying to dynamically look for the `last` member for all objects in a doc there will obviously be more work.

https://rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/avg/

Comment: upvote & Thanks alot for your answer, as you said i need  dynamically look for the `last` , so what should i do for that? please help me